# Target single block with amended theme function?

Tags: theming

I have amended `theme_user_list` so that the user picture is printed out just before the username. I would like to use this function only on the `Who's online` block. Is there anyway I can make this block be the only target for my amended function? Thanks.

```
function MY-THEME_user_list($variables) {
  $users = $variables['users'];
  $title = $variables['title'];
  $items = array();

  if (!empty($users)) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {

      // $items[] = theme('username', array('account' => $user));

      $picture = theme_get_setting('toggle_comment_user_picture') ? theme('user_picture', array('account' => $user)) : '';
      $username = theme('username', array('account' => $user));
      $items[] = $picture . $username;
    }

  }
  return theme('item_list', array('items' => $items, 'title' => $title));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use preprocess_block function as follows:

```
 function mytheme_preprocess_block(&$variables) {
      if ($variables['block_id']->bid === 'target_block_id') {
       $users = $variables['users'];
      $title = $variables['title'];
      $items = array();

      if (!empty($users)) {
        foreach ($users as $user) {

          // $items[] = theme('username', array('account' => $user));

          $picture = theme_get_setting('toggle_comment_user_picture') ? theme('user_picture', array('account' => $user)) : '';
          $username = theme('username', array('account' => $user));
          $items[] = $picture . $username;
        }

      }
      return theme('item_list', array('items' => $items, 'title' => $title));
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Don't preprocess functions just alter or add variables to be output, rather than forming the outputted  HTML itself?